# LaTeX will not work anymore

Tags: errors

My LaTeX was compiling perfectly a minute ago. I wrote some more, added in a citation - now it won't read any of my citations, and is giving me error messages and not allowing me to make a document which I need for a test. 
It repeats this:

```
[1
Non-PDF special ignored!{C:/Users/riley/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/
pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4]

! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.138 5
       \\
?
```

Comment: Welcome, ou probably have `\\ ` where it is not ok. Which is almost everywhere except tabular material.

Comment: Apart from that hint, nobody can answer your question without a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: if everything is in one file: check line 138 and above for a rogue `\\ `

Comment: Debugging tip.  Put the command \end{document} halfway thru your source code.  Now attempt compile.  If it succeeds then your error is after that point, else before.  Then move the \end{document} to the middle of the half where the error is and compile again.  This is a simple binary search.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Otherwise known as the bisection method :P

Answer (score 3):

The error `There's no line here to end` is thrown, if `\linebreak`, `\nolinebreak`, `\newline`, or `\\\\` is called in vertical mode. The error message shows `\\\\` and a line number. Thus, you can go to the source code and check, why `\\\\` is called in vertical mode.

There seems to be a `5` at the begin of line. It's unclear, why it is not set in horizontal mode. Maybe, it is consumed as macro of a previous command or whatever, the previous line would be nice to see. Also, `5` maybe a typo for a non-working shift key and a comment character `%` was the intention to put `\\\\` into a comment.

---

Also, driver options should be checked. The console snippet shows:

```
Non-PDF special ignored!
```

Usually this is caused by wrong driver settings. For example, specifying `dvips` to a driver-dependent package, but using `pdflatex` to compile.